# Return dates that are within 1,3,6,12 months from todays date SSRS/Expression

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I have a table with the following columns:
Sales | Name | Est.close Date

I'm able to display all dates on one table,
I have created 4 tables , for  est. close date next month, 3 , 6, 12 months, what I'm trying to do is display dates that are within 1, 3, 6 and 12 months of today.

I have tried ;

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 6, Parameters!estimateclosedate.Value)
```

And

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1 * DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay,Today()) + 6, Today())
```

Any help , would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I have 2 dates Today() and Fields!estimatedclosedate.Value.
What I'm trying to do is return estimatedclosedates that are within 1,3,6 and 12 months from today.
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I have tried

```
=Fields!estimatedclosedate.Value <> DATEADD(DateInterval.Month,1,Today())
```

but, this turns a boolean , TRUE.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result

Comment: HI @Pravin Deshmukh , have  i provide enough info?

Comment: Do this in sql query instead ?

Comment: how, can you provide an example?

Comment: First tell us, do you want to have range of 1,3,6,12 month's result at once or user input is required for that ?

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh, all at once in 4 separate tables is what im trying to do.

Comment: and by range you mean 3 months back and after today() ?

Comment: estimatedclosedate thats greater then todays date but is whithin 1,3,6,12 months of todays date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show data in different tablixes you should set filter on each tablix.

For example:

[image: tablix filter]

In `Value` for each filter you should set such expressions:

`=dateadd(DateInterval.Month, 1, DateTime.Today)`

`=dateadd(DateInterval.Month, 3, DateTime.Today)`

`=dateadd(DateInterval.Month, 6, DateTime.Today)`

`=dateadd(DateInterval.Month, 12, DateTime.Today)`

**EDIT** (after comments)

Try to use this expression in `exression` field:

`=CDate(Fields!estimatedclosedate.Value)`

It will solve the problem with date format when convert `DateTime` to `String`.

Comment: thanks, Expression = [estimatedclosedate] defaults to Text not Date/Time, can you help me with this?

Comment: Try to use conversion function `CStr` for `dateadd` expression. Or you can use `CDate` function for `Fields!estimatedclosedate.Value`.

Comment: thanks , but im still getting nothing it displays "No Opportunity data"

Comment: What function you use? `CStr` or `CDate`?

Comment: You need to check out that your `Fields!estimatedclosedate.Value` convert to correct date. Conversion from string to datetime can always hide in itself implicit errors.